# What is the special liquid for cleaning the peeing liquid on the floor?

Tags: bathroom

I am a male, and normally, even I try to adjust my peeing direction as in [this post](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20885/at-what-part-of-the-toilet-should-i-aim-to-reduce-the-pee-splashing) . I tried to peeing on these spots already

[image]

However, I still cannot avoid that the ureic water is on the floor, which may cause a bad smell. I am wondering is there any special liquid to wipe this out easily without causing any bad consequences?

Comment: Apart from the right cleaner, you need to make sure that the floor around the toilet bowl is non-absorbing. The standard material is glazed tile. If you have something that can soak up liquids, think about fixing that, either by exchanging the flooring or by waterproofing it. Grout can also be absorbent. For rugs, you need to launder them often (which is why I would advise against them).

Comment: From own experience (which isn't something reliable hence the question you linked to is closed as opinion based) the image you posted is wrong, what works for me, when not sitting, is what Stan said in the lower scored answer: "While standing, place yourself directly in front of the toilet and aim the stream of urine to the centre of the pool of water.". Worth giving this a try, and this way there won't be any pee on the floor.

Comment: The best way is to sit down on the toilet seat while urinating, like women do.  A no brainer.

Comment: Amen to sitting down while you pee. Take a break, meditate and answer some questions on your favorite life hacks Q&A site. Or pee standing up, save 10 seconds per pee all week and then spend your couple of minutes saved on bleaching the floor..

Comment: Aiming is only so effective. Sitting down is the only way to completely eliminate splatter. If a male has respect and appreciation for the person cleaning the toilet, they ought to sit down. And from what I've heard, that's the norm in first world countries other than the US. This macho tradition we have in America of standing up and inevitably pissing everywhere is barbaric. The great outdoors or a gas station is one thing, a home is another.

Answer (score 2):

**What is the special liquid for cleaning the peeing liquid on the floor?**

Generally speaking any anti-bacterial solution or soap will do to clean the area affected. However, if the smell persists I would recommend using the product: [**Fresh-Aire Deodorant Concentrate**](https://www.amazon.ca/12015627-RMC-Fresh-Aire-Deodorant-Concentrate/dp/B015G8KM6W).

[image: RMC Fresh-Aire Deodorant Concentrate]

I work as a supervisor in housekeeping at a mall and this is the very product we use to get odours out. Use a spray bottle to get maximum effect. It is great on urine and many or types of bad smells.

In order to avoid bad aiming, simply sit on the toilet when peeing, at least when at home!

Comment: But it's ok to pee standing up if it's not your toilet.. like if it's at a mall or something? 

Comment: @CaiusJard At least at a mall, someone else cleans up!

Answer (score 1):

Aim it dude!  please!  And thank you for caring enough to ask!  I'm female, and I have all boys in this home, one bathroom, and I clean all around toilet just about bevery other day, and  I don't seem to have issues with this.....is the frequency of me deep cleaning why??  Or is there something I'm missing because I'm not male?  Does aiming not work?  Is there something I should be teaching my young son???  I'm curious.

Also you can normally change the way your urine smells.  drink lots of water and intake foods that help produce a less pungent urine smell, I have not inquired what those foods are, with the exception being asparagus, eating it for days on end is good for you but not your urine....  but I'm sure you can find the foods somewhere whether here or a quick call to your practitioner, if you have the luxury of insurance....if not, Dr google is fairly decent, along with most of his friends most times...

Comment: Aiming is only so effective. Sitting down is the only way to completely eliminate splatter. If a male has respect and appreciation for the person cleaning the toilet, they ought to sit down. And from what I've heard, that's the norm in first world countries other than the US. This macho tradition we have in America of standing up and inevitably pissing everywhere is barbaric. The great outdoors or a gas station is one thing, a home is another.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how well they work on human urine but any major pet store will have products to remove pet odors and stains from cat and dog urine.  They have various enzymes to break down the odor causing elements.